# How do I submit a form's parameters into a (API call) method in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, api

I am making an API call but not saving all of the data to my database, so I assumed that I do not need to make a model for that purpose. However, I do not know how to generate a form for this API call, which is in my controller.

Here is the form in my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for ITHINKINEEDSOMETHINGHERE url: searchApis_path, :method => 'get' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :keyword, :placeholder => 'keyword', input_html: { name: :keyword } %>
  <%= f.input :city, :placeholder => 'city', input_html: { name: :keyword } %>
  <%= f.input :start_date, :placeholder => 'YYYY-MM-DD', input_html: { name: :start_date } %>
  <%= f.input :end_date, :placeholder => 'YYYY-MM-DD', input_html: { name: :end_date } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

My corresponding controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def searchApis
    start_date = params[:start_date]
    end_date = params[:start_date]
    keyword = params[:keyword]
    city = params[:city]

    eventbrite_request = Typhoeus::Request.new('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?q='+keyword+'&sort_by=best&venue.city='+city+'&start_date.range_start='+start_date+'T00:00:00Z&start_date.range_end='+end_date+'T00:00:00Z',
                                  method: :get,
                                  headers: { 'Authorization' => ENV['EVENTBRITE']})
    @response = eventbrite_request.run

    # yelp_request = Typhoeus::Request.new('',
    #                                   )
    # set @result to be the data that I want.
  end


end
```

I am getting an "undefined method 'model_name'" error.

The route which I am making the GET request to is `/searchApis`, so I am guessing that the url in the form should be `searchApis_path`.

So far I have mainly learned how to make a form to generate a new instance of a model, but in this case, the form is to essentially initiate the API call, whose response I will later display under my form. For what it's worth, I want to later be able to save select data from the response JSON into a 'bookmarks' model.

Thanks.

Comment: Try "Object.new" with ["as: :fake"](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes) in inputs

Answer (score 0):

Where you wrote `ITHINKINEEDSOMETHINGHERE` is where the record, typically an ActiveRecord model, usually goes. It is used in the construction of the various field names.

Since it looks like you're doing a search controller, you could put `:search` there, which then would make all your form fields named things like `search[keyword]`

On your backend then, you just have to access the proper params object, which is typically nested under whatever you named the record, so in this case, `params[:search][:keyword]`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

I know you're using simple_form, but it inherits a lot from form_for, so that page is still a good reference

Comment: I actually do not have a search controller. This is all taking place in my home controller. Do I need it along with a search model, then? I am confused because I thought that making a model/controller implies that I am saving it to a database, which I do not intend to do..

Comment: I got it to work by changing the record to :search; however, I'm getting a 400 reponse code from the server. Does my request in the controller have syntax issues?

Comment: You may need to change how the `url:` parameter is provided. If you don't have a named route to `searchApis_path` (you can view named routes by typing `rake routes`) you'll need to use a more explicit representation of the url, such as `controller: 'Home', action: 'searchApis'`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for